# Converter from DateTime to BackGroundColor

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `MyCalendar` class

```
public class MyCalendar
{
  public DateTime Datet { get; set; }
}
```

Using the `GetItems` method, I create elements to be inserted into my `CollectionView`

```
public List<MyCalendar> GetItems(int numberItem)
        {
            var resultList = new List<MyCalendar>();
            for (var i = 0; i<= numberItem; i++)
            {
                nw = nw.AddDays(-1);
                MyCalendar my = new MyCalendar();
                my.Datet=nw;
                resultList.Add(my);
            }
            return resultList;
        }

ObservableCollection<MyCalendar> OCCalendar = new ObservableCollection<MyCalendar>();

    foreach (var s in GetItems(GiorniDaCreare))
    {
       OCCalendar.Add(s);
    }
ColCalendar.ItemsSource = OCCalendar;
```

I then created a `DataColorConverte`r class to change the color of the `CollectionView` `Grid` if the `Datetime.Date` object corresponds to today's date

```
namespace MotiVApp
{
    public class DateColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((MyCalendar)value).Datet.Date == DateTime.Today) return Color.Blue;
            return Color.Gray;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And in the xaml code:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:DateColorConverter x:Key="DateColor" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<CollectionView
    x:Name="ColCalendar"                
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding OCCalendar,Converter={StaticResource DateColor}}">....
```

However, the objects are all without a background. I'm probably wrong in the `Binding` but I'm not sure where

Comment: if you have questions about an answer you received, post a comment on the answer, don't post an entirely new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to bind to the DateTime property on your model

`OCCalendar` is the `ObservableCollection<MyCalendar>` you are using as an `ItemsSource`

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding OCCalendar...
```

`Datet` is the `DateTime` property on the `MyCalendar` model that you want to use

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Datet...
```